# Airflow BashOperator targetting specific path

Tags: python, bash, curl, airflow, string-interpolation

In an airflow task, I want to use a BashOperator to call `CURL` to download a .csv. I want to save it in a specific location. Is this a sensible pattern to use or is there a better way (using templating maybe?):

```
from pathlib import Path
base_path = Path('/home/dan.golding/projects/subproject/results')
```

and then in the `DAG` `with` statement:

```
t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='task_1',
        bash_command=f"curl -X GET 'https://myurl.com/api.php?paramname=paramvalue' > {base_path / 'my_result.csv'}"
        retries=2,
        retry_delay=timedelta(minutes=1))
```

Comment: I don't know what your larger context is, but there are several libraries available to get the contents of a URL without having to start an external program like `curl`.

Comment: @chepner bash libraries? I need this to be an airflow operator so that downloading the .csv is scheduled as part of the DAG. Happy to take suggestions for better options. Is it better to use a python operator instead of a bash operator?

Comment: No, Python libraries, like `urllib` (built-in) or `requests` (3rd party). There's no need to shell out to run `curl` for something like this.

Comment: But is there any reason not to? Because it will be a lot more verbose to define a python function and then call a python library instead since the `PythonOperator` will look just like this `BashOperator`.  If I use `req 
 = requests.get(...)` is it correct to then call `with open(base_path / 'my_result.csv','wb') as file:
    file.write(req.content)` to save it as a csv?

Comment: Shelling out has additional overhead. Every airflow task gets run as a bash command, which then runs python. If you shell out, it's now bash -> python -> bash. If you have multiple DAGs running at once, you will start to feel the memory overhead of all the shells.

Comment: @jhnclvr Not sure I follow, so are you saying that using a `PythonOperator` is more efficient than a `BashOperator` because it would just be bash->python that way?

Comment: @Dan yes, it's more memory efficient to do it in python, because you wont have additional overhead of another bash shell. It might not matter if you don't run much in parallel, but it's good to keep in mind as it isn't particularly obvious when looking at a DAG.

Comment: @jhnclvr thanks. On a related topic, I have some Python tasks that I want to keep in a specific place (so I can easily update them using git) and at present the only way I can figure out to call them from airflow is using a BashOperator i.e. `bash_command=f'python {BASE_PATH / "task_update_propensity.py"}'`

Comment: @Dan maybe put the update logic in a method inside task_update_propensity, import that method, and then call that method from a python_callable in a PythonOperator.

Comment: @jhnclvr but to import it, it would have to be in the same folder as the DAG? And the DAG has to be in airflows DAG folder. Unless I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: @Dan I think it just needs to be somewhere on the PYTHONPATH. Probably good questions to ask in chat: https://gitter.im/apache/incubator-airflow

Comment: Is it not possible to use the SimpleHttpOperator with xcom_push=True and then use a PythonOperator to xcom pull the value and save it to the .csv file? I don't know if xcom push works in this use case, but if it did, I'd say this would be a good way as it would use operators that are intended specifically for that use case.

Comment: Is all of your Airflow execution happening on one node?  Typically I'd save a file like this to cloud storage vs local file storage since there's no guarantee the downstream task would run on the same node in a clustered environment.  Also +1 to using [SimpleHttpOperator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/0ce068e0867f9105f3a1a92d389bc41e6da85991/airflow/operators/http_operator.py#L26); and though you could use XComs here, I try not to use it for sizable data like a JSON object.  Passing the file path into the Jinja template seems like a good idea.

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston yeah just one node. It's not a huge CSV that gets downloaded. Could you post an example of how to do it using a template and (or?) SimpleHttpOperator. Also, if you could post an example of how to call the python file for S3 I'd be happy to move the python scripts there is that is a more robust pattern

Comment: Sure.  Just curious, once the file is saved to disk are you planning to do anything else to it with downstream tasks?

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston I just read it in the downstream tasks.